# how to call a private function from another class if the instance of the object is already there in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, class, project

i want to call this function from another class - OneOffPaymentService

fun toPaymentRequestHistoryEvent(): PaymentRequestHistoryEvent {
return PaymentRequestHistoryEvent(
id = this.id,
userId = this.userId,
paymentDate = this.paymentDate,
type = this.type,
amount = this.amount
)
}

i tried to call this from another class OneOffPaymentService and WithdrawalService

Comment: Not enough information here to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: i have a data class PaymentRequestHistory( 
where i have added a fun fun toPaymentRequestHistoryEvent(): PaymentRequestHistoryEvent {
        return PaymentRequestHistoryEvent( id = this.id,
            userId = this.userId,
            paymentDate = this.paymentDate,
            type = this.type,
            amount = this.amount
        )

Comment: now i have to call this function from other class , where instance of the class is already available

Comment: other class is class WithdrawalService(
    private val avaloqPaymentClient: AvaloqPaymentClient,
    private val avaloqBalanceClient: AvaloqBalanceClient,
    private val withdrawalMinBalanceValidator: WithdrawalMinBalanceValidator,
    private val withdrawalMaxAmountValidator: WithdrawalMaxAmountValidator,
    private val paymentRequestRecorder: PaymentRequestRecorder,
    private val refData: RefData,
    private val clock: Clock,
    private val analyticsSqsPublisher: AnalyticsSqsPublisher
) : Logging {

Comment: You can edit your question and use the code block tool (looks like `{ }` in the toolbar) to add code so it's legible.

Comment: can u check now

Answer (score 0):

i did this
checkPartialWithdrawalConditions(userId, accountId, amountToWithdraw)
val avaloqRequest = PartialWithdrawalAvaloqRequest(amountToWithdraw, refData.withdrawalDescription())
avaloqPaymentClient.makePartialWithdrawal(userId, accountId, avaloqRequest)
paymentRequestRecorder.recordPartialWithdrawal(userId, amount, LocalDate.now(clock))
**.also { analyticsSqsPublisher.publishPaymentHistoryEvent(it.toPaymentRequestHistoryEvent()) }**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).